# Unidentified IC with square marking

Tags: identification

I understand questions regarding IC identification may be a hit or miss, but it's worth a shot.

I have this IC (length 3mm by width 2.2mm) with a grey square marking on the corner. It has 8 pins. Assuming that the grey marking indicates pin one, we have pin one going to a capacitor and then ground. Pin 2 and 3 are grounded. Pin four seems to be the input, an op amp output. Pin five is no contact, as well as pin eight. (I believe) Pin is similar to pin one, going to ground. And pin 7 goes to a hex schmitt trigger. The marking says "SCC."

If any of you have any idea what this would be, or where I could possibly look (I've searched all IC databases that I could find), that would be great.

Picture of IC:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Could you post a second image which includes more of the circuit?

Comment: I think the marking is *SC0*.

Comment: I've updated the picture in the post to include more of the schematic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be the [ADG619BRMZ](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG619_620.pdf) from Analog Devices.
But the wiring of pin 7 is doubtful.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I believe that this is it. Thank-you!